# Getting an ESLint: Unnecessary escape character

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I'm trying to validate a text field but, I'm getting an error for the below regex expression.

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\/\*+;&%?#@!^()_="\-:~`|[\]\{\}\s]*$/i.test(e.target.value)) {
   this.setState({
      newFamilyName: e.target.value,
   });
}
```

Do I need to add any more characters in the Regex so fulfill it.

Comment: I mean... if the escape character is "unnecessary", wouldn't that indicate removing characters rather than adding?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a fix. You can mark it as solved if it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some unnecesary escape characters:
`\/` `\*` `\{` `\}`

You can **fix** it:

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/*+;&%?#@!^()_="\-:~`|[\]{}\s]*$/i.test(e.target.value)) {
   this.setState({
      newFamilyName: e.target.value,
   });
}
```

Or **disable** the rule:

```js
//eslint-disable-next-line
if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\\/\*+;&%?#@!^()_="\-:~`|[\]\{\}\s]*$/i.test(e.target.value)) {
   this.setState({
      newFamilyName: e.target.value,
   });
}
```

Comment: @tejasreevangapalli just edited my answer with the fixed regex

Answer (score 4):

Unnecessary escape character means you have a `\` in front of a character in your regex that you don't actually need.

I plugged the code you posted into https://eslint.org/demo and got:

> 1:20 - Unnecessary escape character: \/. (no-useless-escape)
>   1:22 - Unnecessary escape character: \*. (no-useless-escape)
>   1:47 - Unnecessary escape character: \{. (no-useless-escape)
>   1:49 - Unnecessary escape character: \}. (no-useless-escape)

Which means you didn't need the `\` in front of the `/`, `*`, `{`, or `}` in your regex. Those characters don't need to be escaped since they appeared inside the `[]` group.

Unfortunately the "Fixed Code" thing on the eslint demo site didn't work, but the following code is how you would fix it

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\/*+;&%?#@!^()_="\-:~`|[\]{}\s]*$/i.test(e.target.value)) {
   this.setState({
      newFamilyName: e.target.value,
   });
}
```